# Linq query for EF 4.1 data with nested lists

Tags: .net, wpf, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm working with WPF and EF 4.2 to build a desktop application. I have 3 entities which have cascading one-to-many relationships, Students have zero-or-more schools. Schools have zero-or-more classes attended. I need to display the data in a grouped list showing the student, all their schools then all their classes.

```
Students          School            Class
int Id            int Id            int Id
string Name       string Name       string Subject
int yearBorn      string Address    int Credits
IList<School>     IList<Class>
```

I'm stumped by how to shape the data.

The first issue is that EF 4.2 hides the Id of the entities in Navigation objects so I cannot use them as keys in a "group by".

The next issue is I'm not sure how to include the second level nesting in the groups since I also need to return attributes of objects along the way like Student.Name or School.Address.

Comment: The data schema should look like:

Comment: It's not clear whether you're using EF 4.1 or EF 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to `Group By` - just retrieve the entities in their current object graph.

The standard is something like

```
var context = new EntityContext();
var students = context.Students.Include("Schools").Include("Schools.Classes");
return students;
```

This returns an objects graph containing a set of students, where each students contains a set of schools, where each school contains a set of classes.  The 'grouping' is done by EF - this is the purpose of an ORM, which maps relational database tables into objects in your code.