# Linq query for EF 4.1 data with nested lists bound to WPF form

Tags: wpf, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Following on from this previous question:

> [Linq query for EF 4.1 data with nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111568/linq-query-for-ef-4-1-data-with-nested-lists)

WPF needs `ObservableCollection` to bind the data. I know I can create the `ObservableCollection` by using a list in the constructor like:

```
new ObservableCollection(myListName)
```

But will the nested groups bind to the WPF form or do I need to run the result of my linq query into a pre-defined type with `ObservableCollections` at each level?

Comment: Follow on questions are fine, just don't re-iterate the whole question again. Also just ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directly `ObservableCollection<School>` and `ObservableCollection<Class>` instead of `IList<School>` and `IList<Class>` in your model classes. This way you ensure that Entity Framework will materialize the collection as `ObservableCollection<T>` when you use eager or lazy loading. With `IList<T>` EF would create a `List<T>` as the concrete type and not an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

If your navigation properties are marked as `virtual` you are using lazy loading which means that EF will load the collections automatically as soon as your WPF form wants to access the properties. (The context must not be disposed to get this working.)

If you want to load all collections at once in one query you can use eager loading:

```
var students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(
    context.Students.Include(s => s.Schools.Select(sc => sc.Classes)));
```

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/08/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-model-with-master-detail-wpf-application.aspx) might be helpful as well.